# Facebook javascript/ fbconnect ifuserconnected causing problems

Tags: facebook, authentication, fbml, fbconnect

well I'm reading the fb connect tutorial here

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_Tutorial1

The problem I'm having is near the end of the tutorial, it's saying do do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">  FB.init("apikey","xd_receiver.htm", {"ifUserConnected" : update_fbuser}); </script>
```

as oppose to

```
<script type="text/javascript">  FB.init("apikey","xd_receiver.htm"); </script>
```

Now my problem is, when i use the first one, the login to facebook button I have stops showing, does anyone notice anything wrong with the first one, the second one works fine (just doesnt use the ifuserconnected)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are looking at the old API now deprecated. If you are just starting you better start with the current one. You can read about it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

As to your code. You need to declare callback function `update_fbuser()` that will be called when a user login status changes. You probably don't have it so it breaks. You can find more examples [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Detecting_Connect_Status) (but again those are from old API, now things are completely different).

Comment: I have the function after that bit of code, is that still ok?

Comment: @Belgin If you have that function then something else is wrong. Have you checked firebug console is there any errors? Anyway, I wouldn't spend much time on it as it is old api, better look into new one.

Comment: Recommend any tutorials for the new api?

Comment: @Belgin Sorry I don't know any... Try to start from here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/